# How to Update Row Cursor with Join table in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table A

```
|account|  Unmort  |

|   A   |10.000.000|
```

and a Table B

```
|account|  Jenis |Nominal  | Unmort |Total|

-------------------------------------------
|   A   |  021   |200.000  |    -   |  -  |

|   A   |  028   |3.200.000|    -   |  -  |

|   A   |  023   |7.200.000|    -   |  -  |
```

**how to update to be like this??**

```
|account|  Jenis |Nominal  | Unmort    |Total|

-------------------------------------------
|   A   |  021   |200.000  |    -      |200.000  |

|   A   |  028   |3.200.000| 2.800.000 |400.000  |

|   A   |  023   |7.200.000| 7.200.000 |  0      |
```

for this type of account number jenis **021 Field Unmort Fill set= 0** 
and **Field Total must not be a minus**

Comment: Do you need a solution for both **MySQL** and **SQL Server**? Did you want a query that returns the specified rows (i.e. `SELECT`), or did you need an `UPDATE` statement that modifies the contents of table B?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by Update Row Cursor, but the basic syntax for how to perform an update on one table with data from another would be like this:

```
Update TableB
SET Unmort = t.Unmort
    , Total = t.Total
FROM (Select a.Account, a.unmort, b.Jenis
      FROM TableA a join TableB b on a.Account = b.Account
      WHERE ...some conditions...) t
WHERE TableB.Account = t.Account
     and TableB.Jenis = t.Jenis
```

Comment: to update its own value unmort
021 should not be on the type and for the value unmortz when unmort sum equal to the value in Table A.
and the total field itself should not be a minus.
Her question is how to divide the value of its own unmort on types other than 021 and the total is not a minus,

Comment: Put that into the WHERE clause as noted with ...some conditions....  i.e. WHERE b.Jenis <> '021' and Total (however you are calculating that) > 0.  If this is confusing, put up some sample code to edit.